# Regex to match several slightly different strings

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I work with a charity that does a number of jobs, more than 100, less than 1000 a year. Jobs are identified with a year, and an up to 3 digit serial number, so `2021#123` for instance.

I'm writing a Python report program to pull jobs out of our database, and I'd like be be able to specify ranges of jobs rather like a print dialogue can specify ranges of pages, so a dash separated range `2021#123-45`, or a comma separated list `2021#003,5,07,89,131` as well. I want to be able to parse all of these representations out of text strings.

I'm only interested in the syntax at the moment, the semantics of whether a range is valid is handled later. Even though I have very limited experience of regexes, I felt a one-liner would beat a whole bunch of python `if`s.

The valid strings I want to match are therefore of the form

- `20y#n`          OR
- `20y#n,q,p,r`    OR
- `20y#n-m`

where y is any two digits, and m,n,p,q,r are 1 to 3 digits.

This is a question about the regex. The only python consideration is the use of `r'…'` for a raw string.

I struggled and failed to write a regex that captures any of these forms by trying to match the `year#ddd`, and then OR the different endings. I think I fell foul of the single job form not having an ending at all. I've therefore ended up with this rather agricultural effort, that works, but looks ugly. I didn't put the comments in just for this post; I put them in knowing that if I needed to change things next month, I'd need them.

```
job_patt = r'((?:20\d\d#\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})|(?:20\d\d#\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})+)|(?:20\d\d#\d{1,3}))'
# cap group  (                                                                             )
# non-caps    (?:                      ) (?:                           ) (?:              )
# OR the non-caps, in this L->R order   |                               |
# get year#      20\d\d#                    20\d\d#                         20\d\d#
# get 1 to 3 digits     \d{1,3}                    \d{1,3}                         \d{1,3}
# get one instance of range    -\d{1,3}
# get one or more repeats of list         ',ddd'          (?:,\d{1,3})+
```

What could be done to shorten or tidy up this regex?

Comment: I changed the title so that it's a bit more specific.  Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, I'd changed it just a minute before you. Maybe yours matches my exact problem closely, but it could be more general without losing the flavour of the regex problem - matching several similar strings - as it refers to years and jobs, which aren't relevant to the issue. I'll try to revert it. The fundamental problem that remains unaddressed is that one of the options is null, which I need to think about more.

Comment: Yes, it was supposed to be specific.  Did you intend to revert all my other fixes, too?

Comment: @TobySpeight No, didn't spot those, fixed. I prefer the title as more general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't so much a Python question as it is a RegEx question.  The Python tag is almost irrelevant.

## '+' -vs- '*'

You regex includes two alternates:

- `(?:20\d\d#\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})+)`
- `(?:20\d\d#\d{1,3})`

The difference in these expressions is the first one include one or more repeats of `,\d{1,3}`, where as the second does not include any repeats of that ...

... in other words, you have `20\d\d#\d{1,3}` followed by **0 or more repeats** of `,\d{1,3}`.

So we can replace the `+` modifier with the `*` modifier, and the pair of alternates becomes simply

`(?:20\d\d#\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})*)`

## Common prefix

All three (or rather, both now that the last two have been combined into one) regex's start with `20\d\d#`.  You can factor this out of both patterns.

`20\d\d#` `(?:` `(?:` `\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}` `|` `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})*` `)` `)`

## Capture Groups

There is no point creating a capture group for the entire regex expression.  The entire match is always captured, as group 0.

## Reworked Regex & Example

The regex can be rewritten as:

`r"20\d\d#(?:(?:\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})*))"`

which is shorter, but is still quite unreadable.  It is better for future programmers at the charity (as well as for yourself) to document the regex using the `re.VERBOSE` option.  I find it clearer than comments below the regular expression that try to document the parts of the regular expression through vertically lined up notes.

**Note**: Since comments follow the octothorpe (`#`) character in `re.VERBOSE` mode, we need to escape it (`\#`) to indicate that it is actually a character we want matched, and not the start of a comment.

```py
import re

JOB_PATTERN = re.compile(r"""
                          20\d\d                     # A 4-digit year
                          \#                         # followed by a hash mark
                          (?:                        # followed by either ...
                             (?:\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})        # a range of serial #'s
                             |                          # or
                             (?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})*)   # a list of serial #'s
                          )""", re.VERBOSE)


test_cases = ["junk2021#123-45bar",
              "baz2021#003,5,07,89,131foo"]

for test_case in test_cases:
    m = JOB_PATTERN.search(test_case)
    if m:
        print("Found:", m[0])
```

Output:

```
Found: 2021#123-45
Found: 2021#003,5,07,89,131
```

## *Update*

Based on the OP's response to [RootTwo](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/98633/roottwo)'s comment, named capturing groups are actually desired.  Here is an updated example with RootTwo's enhancement:

```py
import re

JOB_PATTERN = re.compile(
    r"""(?P<year>              # Capturedas "year" ...
           20\d\d                 # a 4-digit year
        )
        \#                     # followed by a hash mark
        (?:                    # followed by either ...
           (?P<range>             # captured as "range" ...
              \d{1,3}-\d{1,3}        # a range of serial #'s
           )
           |                      # or
           (?P<list>              # captured as "list" ...
               \d{1,3}               # a serial number
               (?:,\d{1,3})*         # or list of comma-seperated serial #'s
           )
        )
        """, re.VERBOSE)

test_cases = ["junk2021#123-45bar",
              "baz2021#003,5,07,89,131foo"]

for test_case in test_cases:
    m = JOB_PATTERN.search(test_case)
    if m:
        if m.lastgroup == "range":
            start, end = m['range'].split('-')
            print("Year:", m['year'], " from", start, "to", end)
        else:
            serial_numbers = m['list'].split(',')
            print("Year:", m['year'], " serial #':", serial_numbers)
```

Output:

```
Year: 2021  from 123 to 45
Year: 2021  serial #': ['003', '5', '07', '89', '131']
```

Comment: I came up with an identical pattern, except I used named capture groups so that one can use [`Match.lastgroup()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html#re.Match.lastgroup) to determine if it matched the range or list of jobs.

Comment: @RootTwo That would be a useful improvement.  The OP was simply capturing the entire expression, and **explicitly** using non-capturing groups for the individual details, so I didn't change that in my regex reworkings.

Comment: @RootTwo could I trouble you to write an answer with named capture groups please. Just because I explicitly used  non-capturing groups doesn't mean it's the best thing to do, and I don't like the what appears to be excessive (?: syntax anyway. Maybe it wouldn't shorten it, verbose certain doesn't, but it does make it better.

Comment: @Neil_UK, it is literally the same as AJNeufeld's answer, except in the year part I used `(?P<year>20\d\d)`. in the range part I used `(?P<range>` instead of `(?:`, and in the list part I used `(?<list>` instead of the first `(?:`.

Comment: Note: @RootTwo obviously meant `(?P<list>`, not `(?<list>`.  I've added an updated example with RootTwo's capture group and demonstration of the the `Match.lastgroup` property.

Comment: I was dubious about named groups as they don't appear to offer any advantage in this context. I can test for whether '-' in match as easily as I can test for lastgroup=='range'. The difference appears to be in readability, depending on what one is used to reading.

Comment: The readability benefits of named capture groups span the boundary between the regex and the Python program that uses it.  I salvaged your question by framing it as a regex-only code review.  The "dubious" value of named groups comes from a lack of understanding on how you want to use the results.  You'd need to post your entire Python program as a follow-up question for review if you want a review of the benefits of capture groups -vs- named capture groups -vs- simply matching the entire text and splitting it again in Python.